# Possible bug in PHPMyAdmin v4 when editing a record with large amount of columns

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have a problem while trying to update a record on a MySQL table that have more than 132 fields. The UPDATE query results truncated to 132 fields, causing a null in the next fields.

Here is the structure of a table:

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS caravaggio_models ( id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, Model varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
Type varchar(30) NOT NULL, Mask text NOT NULL, Protocol varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', Client varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', Chamber varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
ADVALUE_LOW tinyint(10) NOT NULL, ADVALUE_HIGH tinyint(10) NOT NULL, SOTIC varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL, NumBytes int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', pwNumber tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '5',
testTime float NOT NULL DEFAULT '20', maxFail int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '5', WakeUp int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '4', SkipTime int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', PW1_max int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', PW2_max int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', PW3_max int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', PW4_max int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PW5_max int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', PW6_max int(11) DEFAULT NULL, PW7_max int(11) DEFAULT NULL, PW8_max int(11) DEFAULT NULL, PW9_max int(11) DEFAULT NULL, PW1_min int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', PW2_min int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', PW3_min int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', PW4_min int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', PW5_min int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', PW6_min int(11) DEFAULT NULL, PW7_min int(11) DEFAULT NULL, PW8_min int(11) DEFAULT NULL, PW9_min int(11) DEFAULT NULL, EEPROM0 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM1 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM2 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM3 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM4 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM5 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM6 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM7 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM8 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM9 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM10 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM11 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM12 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM13 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM14 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM15 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM16 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM17 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM18 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM19 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM20 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM21 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM22 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM23 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM24 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM25 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM26 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM27 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM28 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM29 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM30 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM31 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM32 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM33 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM34 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM35 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM36 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM37 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM38 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM39 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM40 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM41 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM42 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM43 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM44 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM45 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM46 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM47 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM48 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM49 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM50 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM51 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM52 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM53 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM54 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM55 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM56 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM57 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM58 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM59 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM60 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM61 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM62 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM63 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM64 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM65 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM66 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM67 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM68 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM69 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM70 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM71 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM72 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM73 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM74 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM75 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM76 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM77 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM78 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM79 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM80 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM81 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM82 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM83 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM84 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM85 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM86 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM87 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM88 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM89 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM90 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM91 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM92 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM93 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM94 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM95 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM96 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM97 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM98 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM99 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM100 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM101 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM102 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM103 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM104 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM105 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM106 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM107 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM108 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM109 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM110 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM111 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM112 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM113 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM114 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM115 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM116 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM117 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM118 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM119 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM120 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM121 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM122 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM123 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM124 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM125 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM126 int(11) DEFAULT '0', EEPROM127 int(11) DEFAULT '0', MASK0 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK1 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255',
MASK2 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK3 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK4 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK5 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK6 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK7 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK8 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK9 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255',
MASK10 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK11 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK12 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK13 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK14 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK15 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK16 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK17 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255',
MASK18 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK19 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK20 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK21 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK22 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK23 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK24 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK25 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255',
MASK26 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK27 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK28 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK29 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK30 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK31 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK32 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK33 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255',
MASK34 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK35 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK36 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK37 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK38 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK39 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK40 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK41 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255',
MASK42 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK43 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK44 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK45 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK46 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK47 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK48 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK49 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255',
MASK50 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK51 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK52 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK53 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK54 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK55 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK56 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK57 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255',
MASK58 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK59 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK60 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK61 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK62 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK63 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK64 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK65 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255',
MASK66 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK67 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK68 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK69 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK70 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK71 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK72 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK73 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255',
MASK74 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK75 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK76 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK77 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK78 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK79 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK80 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK81 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255',
MASK82 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK83 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK84 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK85 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK86 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK87 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK88 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK89 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255',
MASK90 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK91 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK92 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK93 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK94 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK95 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK96 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK97 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255',
MASK98 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK99 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK100 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK101 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK102 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK103 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK104 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK105 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255',
MASK106 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK107 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK108 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK109 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK110 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK111 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK112 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK113 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255',
MASK114 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK115 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK116 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK117 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK118 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK119 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK120 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK121 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255',
MASK122 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK123 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK124 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK125 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK126 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', MASK127 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255', cs_base tinyint(4) NOT NULL, logo text NOT NULL, photo text NOT NULL, verifyEE tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', testISO tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', last_change timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, PRIMARY KEY (id),
KEY NumBytes (NumBytes) ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 CHECKSUM=1 COMMENT='Tabella modelli' AUTO_INCREMENT=583 ;

And here is the result query while trying to edit (o copy) a record:

INSERT INTO `burnin`.`caravaggio_models` (`id`, `Model`, `Type`, `Mask`, `Protocol`, `Client`, `Chamber`, `ADVALUE_LOW`, `ADVALUE_HIGH`, `SOTIC`, `NumBytes`, `pwNumber`, `testTime`, `maxFail`, `WakeUp`, `SkipTime`, `PW1_max`, `PW2_max`, `PW3_max`, `PW4_max`, `PW5_max`, `PW6_max`, `PW7_max`, `PW8_max`, `PW9_max`, `PW1_min`, `PW2_min`, `PW3_min`, `PW4_min`, `PW5_min`, `PW6_min`, `PW7_min`, `PW8_min`, `PW9_min`, `EEPROM0`, `EEPROM1`, `EEPROM2`, `EEPROM3`, `EEPROM4`, `EEPROM5`, `EEPROM6`, `EEPROM7`, `EEPROM8`, `EEPROM9`, `EEPROM10`, `EEPROM11`, `EEPROM12`, `EEPROM13`, `EEPROM14`, `EEPROM15`, `EEPROM16`, `EEPROM17`, `EEPROM18`, `EEPROM19`, `EEPROM20`, `EEPROM21`, `EEPROM22`, `EEPROM23`, `EEPROM24`, `EEPROM25`, `EEPROM26`, `EEPROM27`, `EEPROM28`, `EEPROM29`, `EEPROM30`, `EEPROM31`, `EEPROM32`, `EEPROM33`, `EEPROM34`, `EEPROM35`, `EEPROM36`, `EEPROM37`, `EEPROM38`, `EEPROM39`, `EEPROM40`, `EEPROM41`, `EEPROM42`, `EEPROM43`, `EEPROM44`, `EEPROM45`, `EEPROM46`, `EEPROM47`, `EEPROM48`, `EEPROM49`, `EEPROM50`, `EEPROM51`, `EEPROM52`, `EEPROM53`, `EEPROM54`, `EEPROM55`, `EEPROM56`, `EEPROM57`, `EEPROM58`, `EEPROM59`, `EEPROM60`, `EEPROM61`, `EEPROM62`, `EEPROM63`, `EEPROM64`, `EEPROM65`, `EEPROM66`, `EEPROM67`, `EEPROM68`, `EEPROM69`, `EEPROM70`, `EEPROM71`, `EEPROM72`, `EEPROM73`, `EEPROM74`, `EEPROM75`, `EEPROM76`, `EEPROM77`, `EEPROM78`, `EEPROM79`, `EEPROM80`, `EEPROM81`, `EEPROM82`, `EEPROM83`, `EEPROM84`, `EEPROM85`, `EEPROM86`, `EEPROM87`, `EEPROM88`, `EEPROM89`, `EEPROM90`, `EEPROM91`, `EEPROM92`, `EEPROM93`, `EEPROM94`, `EEPROM95`, `EEPROM96`, `EEPROM97`, `EEPROM98`, `EEPROM99`, `EEPROM100`) VALUES (NULL, 'prova', 'Test', '01', 'Test', 'Test', '000', '23', '27', '01 04', '128', '5', '20', '5', '4', '0', '320', '320', '620', '900', '2200', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '280', '280', '580', '780', '2000', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '4', '98', '0', '112', '0', '0', '-1', '-1', '0', '75', '35', '25', '173', '18', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '17', '0', '30', '13', '3', '160', '15', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '-1', '25', '96', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '85', '85', '-1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '-1', '131', '0', '0', '0', '0', '255', '255', '255', '255', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '');

As you can see, fields after EEPROM100 are missing, and EEPROM100 is set to empty value ('') instead of correct value. 
PhpMyAdmin version 3 doesn't have this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed here https://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/bugs/4319/ I solved by increasing max_input_vars var in php.ini from 1000 to 5000.
Thanks to the Phpmyadmin community